# Pinterest token not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, pinterest

I have implemented pinterest oAuth2 custom owin middleware in MVC 5 like facebook, google. After getting token I tried to access pinterest user information by using user authorization endpoint https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/pins/ , it giving below error :

{
    "status": "failure",
    "message": "Authorization failed.",
    "code": 3,
    "data": null
}

Comment: yes, you correct. It's not working now. It's not a duplicate question. :(